# Deselect RecyclerView cell but tapping anywhere outside of it

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a linear layout with three recylerviews in it that all scroll horizontally. When the user taps a cell within one of the recycler views it is "highlighted" and in the selected state. I need to de-select this cell when the user taps anywhere outside of it.

I have tried adding an onClickListener to the parent LinearLayout view but it isn't hit every time. I have also tried adding a view ontop of the recycler views with a Framelayout as the parent layout to the LinearLayout and View but this prevented the user from being able to scroll the view across.

I have also tried using `android:descendantFocusability` but was unable to get it working if a viable option.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/parent_timeline_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_1"
    ....
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_2"
    ....
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_3"
    ....
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Layout View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to add onTouchListeners to each of the recyclerViews as well as the base rootView. I then implemented `SimpleOnGestureListener` for each to know when a single tap had been triggered and not just any touch. This meant scrolling performed as normal!

The CustomGestureClass:

```
internal class RecyclerViewGesture : SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        unselectAllCells.postValue(true)
        return false
    }
}
```

Then in the fragment I created an instance of the class

```
recyclerViewDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(context!!, RecyclerViewGesture())
```

Then I used an `onTouchListener` then returned the gesture

```
  myRecyclerView.setOnTouchListener { p0, event ->
            recyclerViewDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
```

I created three of these for each of the recycler views and then used an onclickListener for the root view. I used a MutableLiveData value to post to when any of the Gestures/OnClick where hit and unselected all cells in the observer

```
     unselectAllCells.observe(this, Observer {
        if(unselectAllCells.value!!){
            unselectAnyGraphicalImageCell()
        }
    })
```

Hopefully this can save someone some pain some day!